# REST api - Updating table with POST from view

Tags: php, rest, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3

I'm new to RESTful web services and still figuring out the design/architecture aspect coupled with MVC pattern. I am using Codeigniter framework to implement MVC.

I had a pretty simple question. I am using using form data to update a table in my database. I have written an api that will do this:

http://www.example.com/api/resource/tablename/?param1=info1...

Typical api. What I wanted to know was, in the MVC pattern should I be using cURL in my VIEW to POST data and update my table with the form data or should I still be send the POST data to my controller and make the api call from the controller to update the table.

To me it seems arbitrary at this point as both will accomplish the same thing but what is the standard practice? Is it okay to directly communicate with you api from the VIEW to update your db table??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it okay to directly communicate with you api from the VIEW to
>   update your db table??

Yes, it is...in fact that is pretty much what you should do in this case! Send your data directly to the API. Your API should do all data validation and return an error message (in a standardized format like JSON, XML etc) if any data validation fails OR perform whatever action it needs to do with the POSTed data. A great benefit in doing so would be that your API can be used by any caller and would be a complete ecosystem by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your intended applications I can say this:

Typically you want to try and keep any processing logic (PHP) out of your views if possible. The whole point of the controller is to handle transaction operations from your model and then pass it to your view. So if you are using an API to gather some data from a service that is intended to be used/manipulated in your view then the logical location for that would be in the controller.

The MVC pattern isn't a hard and fast law of X goes in Y and Y goes in Z. It is a pattern that makes it easy to extend and abstract your data gathering, processing logic, and visual layouts.

Technically depending on the application and how you planned to use it you could create a model for the API so that it could be used in multiple controllers without the need to re-write it.